# Optimizing a SELECT with sub SELECT query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
Select id,
       (Select sum(totalpay) 
          from Table2 t 
         where t.id = a.id  
           and t.transamt > 0 
           and t.paydt BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate-0-7) and TRUNC(sysdate-0-1)) As Pay
  from Table1 a
```

In spite of having indexes on transamt, paydt and id, the cost of the sub-query on Table2 is very expensive and requires a FULL TABLE scan.

Can this sub-query be optimized in any other way? 
Please help.

Comment: 1. "and requires a FULL TABLE scan." - why not optimize it so that it didn't require a full scan? 2. `sysdate-0-7` - what's that?

Comment: Do you have three separate indexes on these columns? Or a composite one? You may also want to include totalpay in that index, then the query can be served without touching the table at all.

Comment: Please show the full explain plan output

Comment: @Thilo: "without touching the table at all" --- are you positive? What would that index include by your proposal?

Comment: Could you reproduce your schema on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? I tried your query with [seperate indexes](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca5a1/1), [composite index](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47094/1) and in both cases there is no full table scan on table2 in execution plan.

Comment: I added a composite index on all 4 columns id, totalpay,transamt,paydt and also an individual index on totalpay. This reduced the cost. @Thilo can you add your comment as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t.id,
       sum(totalpay) as Pay
  from Table2 t join Table1
 Where t.id = Table1.id
   and t.transamt > 0 
   and t.paydt BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate-0-7) and TRUNC(sysdate-0-1)
 group by t.id
```

Comment: This isn't the same... There may be IDs in the first table that don't exist in the second.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select a.id,
       pay.totalpay
  from Table1 a
       (Select t.id, sum(totalpay) totalpay
          from Table2 t 
         where t.transamt > 0 
           and t.paydt BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate-0-7) and TRUNC(sysdate-0-1)
         group by t.id
       ) As Pay
 where a.id = pay.id
```

push group by joining columns (id column in this example) into subquery to calculate results for all values in Table2 and then join with Table1 table. 
In original query you calculate result for every crow from Table1 table reading full Table2 table.

Comment: Including an explanation of how your code works always makes a better answer.